# Getting Error "addEventListener is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pick my color from the color picker and then draw with this color in my canvas.
I get the Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: colors.addEventListener is not a function
at window.onload
```

I use the [npm color picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/a-color-picker).

I get the Error at the call of the function:

```
colors.addEventListener('click', function(event)
```

My html:

```
  <div class="picker"
       acp-color="#EFE9E7"
       acp-palette="#f44336|#e91e63|#9c27b0|#673ab7|#3f51b5|#2196f3|#03a9f4|#00bcd4|
     #009688|#4caf50|#8bc34a|#cddc39|#cddc39|#ffeb3b|#ffc107|#ff9800|#ff5722|#795548|#9e9e9e|#20707|#befe7ee|#9e9e9e|#9e9e5e|#9e4e9e">
  </div>

  <div class="right-block">
    <canvas id="paint-canvas" width="640" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/a-color-picker@1.1.8/dist/acolorpicker.js"></script>
  <script src="./paint.js"></script>
```

My js code

```
var colors="#f44336";

AColorPicker.from('.picker')
    .on('change', (picker, color) => {
        colors= color;

    });



var canvas = document.getElementById("paint-canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var boundings = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();



window.onload = function () {

    // Definitions


    // Specifications
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black'; // initial brush color
    context.lineWidth = 1; // initial brush width
    var isDrawing = false;

    loadInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => this.load(event));

    // Handle Colors


    colors.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        context.strokeStyle = event.target.value || 'black';
    });

    // Mouse Down Event
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        setMouseCoordinates(event);
        isDrawing = true;

        // Start Drawing
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    });

    // Mouse Move Event
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        setMouseCoordinates(event);

        if(isDrawing){
            context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            context.stroke();
        }
    });




    // Mouse Up Event
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
        setMouseCoordinates(event);
        isDrawing = false;
    });

    // Handle Mouse Coordinates
    function setMouseCoordinates(event) {
        mouseX = event.clientX - boundings.left;
        mouseY = event.clientY - boundings.top;
    }

};
```

Comment: Can you edit it in my js Fiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/ManuelRiedl29/k9mbt7ys/9/

Comment: Where is `loadInput` variable defined??

Comment: Added solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that, you need to change your `context.strokeColor` when the event fires up on the color change when picked, So you should Create a reference of the `AColorPciker` element and use its event emitter when your document is loaded

Then you can easily change your `strokeColor`, I hope this works for you.

I am adding the edited script, which should work for you.

```
// Initializing the color picker reference
var colorPicker = AColorPicker.from('.picker');



var canvas = document.getElementById("paint-canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var boundings = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();


window.onload = function () {

    // Definitions


    // Specifications
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black'; // initial brush color
    context.lineWidth = 1; // initial brush width
    var isDrawing = false;

    // Here I am using the refernce of AColorPicker to set the context Stroke color, when the change is emitted on the color change
    colorPicker.on('change', (picker, color) => {
      context.strokeStyle = color;
    });



    // Mouse Down Event
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
        setMouseCoordinates(event);
        isDrawing = true;

        // Start Drawing
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    });

    // Mouse Move Event
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        setMouseCoordinates(event);

        if(isDrawing){
            context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            context.stroke();
        }
    });




    // Mouse Up Event
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
        setMouseCoordinates(event);
        isDrawing = false;
    });

    // Handle Mouse Coordinates
    function setMouseCoordinates(event) {
        mouseX = event.clientX - boundings.left;
        mouseY = event.clientY - boundings.top;
    }


};
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add an event listener to a string.

```js
var colors="#f44336";

colors.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        context.strokeStyle = event.target.value || 'black';
    });
```

String does not have this method. Given the assumption it remains a string after the picker on change event.

Comment: I understand the problem, but i am not able to get my project working. I created a jsfiddle. Can you edit it there ? https://jsfiddle.net/ManuelRiedl29/k9mbt7ys/9/

Comment: Please rephrase your question and explain what you are trying to achieve with this event listener.

Comment: I simply want to pick my color in the color-picker and draw with this picked color in my canvas.